# Helper Activity to display Fragment?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

Does anyone know if an Activity exists in Android that could accept a Fragment and simply display it?

This is extremely easy to write, but I'm just wondering if Android provides a helper class like this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luckily it does not exists. There's no point of having such things like in the system which you can implement in 3-5 lines of code yourself (I personally do not like ListActivity too if you ask).

Comment: I agree with you about ListActivity, I hate that thing.

Answer (score -1):

Yes a fragment transaction accepts a fragment to display it.

```
    final FragmentManager fragManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();

    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragManager
            .beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(myFragment, "xx"
            + REQUEST_CODE_PICK_ACCOUNT);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

The code below creates a fragment and the fragment selects a user.  A fragment doesn't need a UI.

```
final FragmentManager fragManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();

    Fragment f = new Fragment() {
        @Override
        public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
            super.onAttach(activity);
            startActivityForResult(AccountPicker.newChooseAccountIntent(null, null,
                    new String[]{"com.google"}, false, null, null, null, null), REQUEST_CODE_PICK_ACCOUNT);
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                     Intent data) {
            if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PICK_ACCOUNT) {
                String mEmail = "";
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    if (data.hasExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME)) {
                        mEmail = data
                                .getStringExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);
                    }
                }
                if (mActivity != null) {
                    //save the email.
                    MyPreferences.putString(mActivity, SettingApplication.USER_EMAIL, mEmail);
                }
                doUser();
            }
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            fragManager.beginTransaction().remove(this).commit();
        }
    };
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragManager
            .beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(f, "xx"
            + REQUEST_CODE_PICK_ACCOUNT);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: A FragmentTransaction is not an Activity. Please read my question carefully.

Comment: minus 1 you should be happy anyone even tried to help.

Comment: Lol I wasn't insinuating anything regarding your response. I was pointing out that your answer does not apply to my question. You want to throw a fit, feel free :) I can minus 1 too you know ;)